# How can I use GotoBlas library in VS2010 C++ on Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I downloaded GotoBLAS library at http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/tacc-projects/gotoblas2/ and I want to use `syev()` function to calculate eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix. But I'm a newbie with opensource library and I don't know how to use it? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why are you using an almost 2 revisions out of date compiler?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as suggested by its name, GotoBLAS means to provide BLAS only, but its version 2.0 also distributes and compiles LAPACK, which contains the functions `ssyev` for single-precision float and `dsyev` for double-precision of your interests. In order words, it is equivalent to say that you want to use LAPACK in C++ with visual studio 2010.

I guess the problem is not how to use libraries in VS2010 but how to use LAPACK package with C++. Here is a little hint: LAPACK is written in Fortran. Due to historical reasons, libraries written by Fortran can be directly accessed by C. In C++, specifically, you need to declare the function, for instance, dot-product for double `ddot` by

```
extern "C"{ 
    double ddot_(
        const int*    n,   // dimension 
        const double* dx,  // []vector x
        const int*    incx,// index increment of each access of x
        const double* dy,  // []vector y
        const int*    incy // index increment of each access of y
    );
}
```

In Fortran, every function argument is passed by reference, so in C/C++, we need to pass arguments by pointers, even for scalars.

Once you declare the function prototypes, you can use it everywhere. In this case, we can call it by, for example,

```
double x[] = {1,2,3};
double y[] = {1,1,1};
int    inc = 1;
int    n   = 3;
std::cout << ddot_(&n, x, &inc, y, &inc) << std::endl;
```

The printed result should be `6`. Pay extra attention at where to put `&` and where not to. It is very easy to make a mistake.

Make sure you put `lapack` (or the name of your GotoBLAS library) in project library setup.
In command line with g++ for example,

```
g++ -llapack your_file_name.cpp -o output_file_name
```

Hope this helps!